# What is the best way to enable nested shortcodes?

Tags: shortcode

Is this the best way to enable nested shortcodes?:

`add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode' );`

I keep finding mixed results and want to be sure I won't break anything else!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes

Everything you need to know about nested shortcodes in WP

Comment: That mentions "provided their handler functions support it by recursively calling do_shortcode()" - So, doing it like above wouldn't be the way to go?

Comment: Maybe a more appropriate question would be, would setting that above to the default priority (10) cause issues I'm unaware of?

Comment: The line of code you have posted is useless. You are adding the do_shortcode function to the filter the_content. WordPress already does that automatically. Applying it again wont make things recursive. As the codex says: "provided their handler functions support it by recursively calling do_shortcode()"

Comment: What shortcode are you nesting?

Comment: It's just a handful of different column shortcodes, they don't rely on do_shortcode($content) in the shortcodes. It does work with the filter changed to priority 10 but I think I'll just rewrite them to use do_shortcode($content) as it states. I appreciate your quick replies.

Comment: Please join chat because I think you are missing the point of shortcodes here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a specific answer, to avoid relying on the official WP docs in the other answer (which, it seems, don't really offer the explicit instructions anyway).

#### Run do_shortcode() on the input

Here is an example registration of a shortcode that supports nested shortcodes inside of it:

```php
function register_example_shortcode_with_nesting($atts, $text) {

    $output = do_shortcode($text);
    
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('example_shortcode_with_nesting', 'register_example_shortcode_with_nesting');
```

You would use this like:

```
[example_shortcode_with_nesting]
[nested_shortcode]
[other_nested_shortcode]
[/example_shortcode_with_nesting]
```

The key ingredient, of course, is running the `$text` content (that comes from between the opening and closing shortcode tag) through `do_shortcode()`. By default WP grabs the first shortcode it can see, then ignores any shortcodes inside that, so we need to tell it to "look again", and this code does the trick.

Of course, the example above does nothing useful, you'll need to take action on the `$output` using `$atts` etcetera to make it do something.

#### Warnings about nesting shortcodes with closing tags

- This **does** support having shortcodes inside that have closing tags, i.e. ones where there is $text content.
- But it can go wrong if you have several of the same shortcode nested as siblings.
- If you have the same shortcode several times, WP can get confused about which "opening" tag applies to which "closing" tag, and it will automatically apply the first instance to the first closing.

So here's my rule of thumb: **If a nested shortcode has a closing tag, it must either be first, the only of it's kind, or all of the matching nested shortcodes need to have closing tags.**

So an example like this won't give you what you expect:

```
[example_shortcode_with_nesting]
[nested_shortcode id=1]
[nested_shortcode id=2][/nested_shortcode]
[/example_shortcode_with_nesting]
```

What happens? You get the first shortcode with `id=1` rendered with the `[/nested_shortcode]` as its closing tag, and the `id=2` shortcode as its unrendered content! Yikes!

So like I said above, either avoid having the same shortcode multiple times, or make sure that ALL of them have both the opening and closing shortcodes!

Answer (score 0):

Mine is not really an answer but since I have wasted a lot of time on this question, I would like to underline an aspect highlighted by [jerclarke's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/406729/32321): **if the nested shortcode and the one it contains are the same, the code will not work**.

As stated in the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes):

The shortcode parser correctly deals with nested shortcode macros, provided their handler functions support it by recursively calling do_shortcode():

```
[tag-a]
   [tag-b]
      [tag-c]
   [/tag-b]
[/tag-a]
```

However the parser will fail if a shortcode macro is used to enclose another macro of the same name:

```
[tag-a]
   [tag-a]
   [/tag-a]
[/tag-a]
```